# Old version of file in Sharepoint library doesn't exist when checked with FileSystemObject

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Given a file path to a prior version of a document in a Sharepoint list, I want to see if the file exists.  My code:

```
Sub test()

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If fso.FileExists("\\wss\GE\sites\Station\_vti_history\6656\x\x_1.xlsm") Then
 Debug.Print "file exists"
Else
 Debug.Print "file doesn't exist"
End If

End Sub
```

I know that this file exists because when I put the URL into Internet Explorer:

```
http://wss/GE/sites/Station/_vti_history/6656/x/x_1.xlsm
```

then the file opens successfully.

I think it's a problem with accessing `_vti_history` through the Windows file system, because Windows Explorer lets me open:

```
\\wss\GE\sites\Station\
```

but not

```
\\wss\GE\sites\Station\_vti_history\
```

If I pass in

```
fso.FileExists("\\wss\GE\sites\Station\x\x_1.xlsm")
```

instead, then `FileExists` returns true.

How can I check for the existence of this old file version using VBA?

EDIT: So far, I've had success by making a GET request with MSXML2.XMLHTTP, and checking whether or not the httpResponse is 200, but ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't involve actually downloading the file.

Comment: Use a HEAD request instead of GET

Comment: It's possible/likely that in the URL `_vti_history` doesn't represent a physical directory, but is used for routing the request to the appropriate handler - basically an instruction to "look up the history for the following parameters"

Comment: https://ankushdev.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/version-history-sharepoint-document-library/